# How to avoid the race condition detected in the following code?

Tags: java, race-condition

Consider the snippet taken from [here](http://www.javaspecialists.eu/archive/Issue192.html):

```
// event
public class Event { }
// An Event Listener
public interface EventListener {
        public void onEvent(Event e);
}

// inner class instances contain a hidden reference to the enclosing instance
public class ThisEscape {
    private final int num;

    public ThisEscape(EventSource source) {
        source.registerListener(new EventListener() {

            @Override
            public void onEvent(Event e) {
                doSomething(e);
            }
        });
        num = 42;
    }

    private void doSomething(Event e) {
        if (num != 42) {
            System.out.println("Race condition detected at " + new Date());
        }
    }
}
// event source

public class EventSource extends Thread {
    private final BlockingQueue<EventListener> listeners = 
                                new LinkedBlockingQueue<EventListener>();

    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            try {
                listeners.take().onEvent(null);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    public void registerListener(EventListener eventListener) {
        listeners.add(eventListener);
    }
}


// testing the conditions

public class ThisEscapeTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventSource es = new EventSource();
        es.start();
        while (true) {
            new ThisEscape(es);
        }
    }
}
```

To consolidate, we have 2 threads

```
// Main Thread
// Event Source
```

In the Event Source thread, there is a BlockingQueue to store EventListener.
In the run method for the same thread,

The **consuming EventSource thread** keeps taking objects out of the blocking queue, and processes them. If the same thread tries to take an object out of an empty queue, the very same thread is blocked until a `producing thread` (*Main Thread*) puts an object into the queue.

Since these 2 operations (below) are not atomic, due to some unlucky timimg, so between the same 2 operations, it is highly likely that the EventSource may find that **num != 2** & hence the race condition.

```
source.registerListener(new EventListener() {   // OPERATION 1      
    @Override
    public void onEvent(Event e) {
        doSomething(e);
    }
    });
    num = 42;                                       // OPERATION 2
}
```

Since as suggested and seen clearly, the inner class instances contain a hidden reference to the enclosing instance.

While the lock has been acquired by the same thread(*Main Thread*), the non-synchronised method   `doSomething()` can still be accessed by another thread (in this case EventSource) at the same time, I see that even synchronizing the 2 operations above won't avoid the race conditions. Is my understanding correct?
I mean

```
 public ThisEscape(EventSource source) {
     synchronized(this){                // SYNCHRONISED
         source.registerListener(new EventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onEvent(Event e) {
                doSomething(e);
            }
         });
    num = 42;
    }
}
```

And the only way to avoid the race condition is make the `doSomething()` method also synchronized, **apart from synchronising the 2 operations**?

Thirdly, I see whether the field is final or not, it doesn't makes any difference. The race condition will still be there. What exactly is the author's point of discussion about the **final** field (apart from making `private final int num = 42`)?

Comment: Is there a reason you don't simply move the assignment `num = 42` above registering the listener? That's what the "javaspecialist" is trying to tell you.

Comment: @meriton: Thanks, Yes, exactly. I am asking for the solution other than this. In fact, I am trying to say the same thing as can be seen in the last line of the question.

Comment: ... and *why* are you ignoring the best practice? (The practice wouldn't be best if there existed better solutions, would it?)

Comment: The answer to "How can i fix the problems caused by doing 'stupid thing'" is usually "Stop doing the 'stupid thing'". What benefit do you think you get by publishing `this` in the constructor? And why do you think it is easier to fix it by using weird things, instead of reordering your statements?

Comment: @k5_: I am new to Java. Doing stupid things. That's how I learn things.

Comment: @ShirgillFarhanAnsari everybody does stupid things from time to time. But once you realized the thing is stupid, you should not keep insisting doing it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you already realized, publishing `this` in the constructor is a really bad idea.

This is a good way around it; Use a factory method.

```
public static ThisEscape newInstance(EventSource source){
   final ThisEscape instance = new ThisEscape();
   source.registerListener(new EventListener() {

        @Override
        public void onEvent(Event e) {
            instance.doSomething(e);
        }
    }
   return instance;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

By calling `registerListener()` before initializing `num` field, you are obviously exposing yourself to the risk of num being accessed before it is set. What's more is that, `num` is accessed from a different thread, so there is no guarantee that once it is set, the correct value is going to be read.

The possible solution would be to intitialize `num` beforehand

```
public static class ThisEscape {
    private final int num = 42;

    public ThisEscape(EventSource source) {
        source.registerListener(e -> doSomething(e));
    }
    //...
}
```

Or to make it volatile and set it before `registerListener()` is called

```
public static class ThisEscape {
    private volatile int num;

    public ThisEscape(EventSource source) {
        num = 42;
        source.registerListener(e -> doSomething(e));
    }
    //...
}
```

Edit: Thanks @AndyTurner, and @ShirgillFarhanAnsari for pointing out the mistake.

Comment: Simply reversing the statements doesn't guarantee to remove the problem. You only get the guarantee that the assignment happens before `doSomething` is called if you register the listener after the constructor completes, because of the happens-before behaviour of final field assignment.

Comment: The first solution is fine. The second is not as I came to know that its not all guaranteed that an instruction/ operation which comes before another is guaranteed to be executed before that same another.

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with escaping `this` pointer. The fact that `num` is in the outer class doesn't change the fact that parallel activities need to be synchronized.

As you noted, there are 2 operations:

1. `registerListener`
2. Set `num = 42`

Now the `onEvent` callback can be called shortly after `registerListener` returns or even before it returns, because it is asynchronous. In any case either **before** or **after** `num = 42`. It needs to be synchronized or ordered properly.